# How to create custom post type item by submitting form on frontend in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a form in my Wordpress theme and I want to create custom post when I submit that form and to fill that custom post with some data from the form. What would it be?  A plugin or maybe just several strings of code in functions.php? Kindly show me proper directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go to this link "[insert post from frontend](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/posting-via-the-front-end-inserting--wp-27034)"

Hope the above tutorial will full fill your requirement also you can use "[frontier-post](https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontier-post/)" plugin to do your task.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it is create a [*Page Template*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) with the code to capture the form's post data. You'll also need *[wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)*.

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: My Custom Form Page 
**/
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['my_form'])):
// do something with the data
    $post = array();
    $post['post_title']         = $_POST['user_title'];
    $post['post_content']       = $_POST['user_content']);
    $post['post_type']      = 'my_custom_post_type';
    $postID                 = wp_insert_post($post);
endif;
// continue to template with form
?>
```